# What is ApoCas9 in the CRISPR-Cas9 system?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology

I am currently reading an article about a particular assay of Cas9 nucleases. In one of the experiments, they have used ApoCas9 (Apo variants of other CRISPR nucleases) as some sort of control.

But the whole article they have not defined ApoCas9? I did check online of definition and activity of ApoCas9, but came across without any fruitful results.

[A universal method for sensitive and cell-free
detection of CRISPR-associated nucleases](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlepdf/2019/sc/c8sc03426e)

Answer (score 1):

In general, "apo" is used to indicate an [apoenzyme](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Structural_Biochemistry/Enzyme/Apoenzyme_and_Holoenzyme) — that is the protein part of an enzyme without essential cofactor(s).

This is actually defined in the **Experimental** section of the paper:

> Cas9/Cpf1 without gRNA (ApoCas9/Cpf1)

So, in this case ApoCas9 is Cas9 endonuclease that is not bound to a guide RNA.

Comment: Thank you. I clearly missed that from the experimental section.